Selecting Button with Selenium Python
Hi I am practicing and trying to close out of a pop up that occurs when you go to a site. There is an "x" in the top right corner that I want to click once the site opens. I get the site open but can't figure out how to identify the "x" button ID to click and close it. I am new to HTML and Python. Using MAC/safari.
current code:
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('https://littlesleepies.com/collections/vip-early-access?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=vip_5_16_2024')


import time

def decline_offer():
    decline = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//[@id='closeIconSvg']")))
    decline.click()

Go easy on me I am a newbie lol.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. This includes HTML.

A few things...

You don't have to click the SVG tag... you can just click the enclosing BUTTON,
<button id="closeIconContainer" data-testid="closeIcon" aria-label="Dismiss this popup" data-attn-element-id="st1q" class="css-2vqtum">

It has an ID so we can use (By.ID, "closeIconContainer").

This whole popup is inside of an IFRAME so you'll need to switch into the IFRAME, click the close button, and then return to the default context.

You are waiting for presence and then clicking. Presence just means the element is in the DOM, not that it's ready to be interacted with. Selenium, by design, will not interact (click, .text, .send_keys(), etc.) with an element that is not visible. If you are going to click an element, wait for clickable using EC.element_to_be_clickable(). If you are going to use .text, .send_keys(), etc. wait for visible using EC.visibility_of_element_located().


The code below has been tested and is working...
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

URL = "https://littlesleepies.com/collections/vip-early-access?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=vip_5_16_2024"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(URL)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "attentive_creative")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "closeIconContainer"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()


Thank you so so much! I really appreciate your explanation!

It's different for Svg
Try this: //button[@id='closeIconContainer']/*[name()='svg'][@id='closeIconSvg']

Couple of things to try:
1st, it looks like you are trying to click on the icon element, rather than the button tag. Try //[@id='closeIconContainer'] instead.
2nd, I know that you're using Safari, but this is how I would find the xpath using Chrome.
Rather than using  "//[@id='closeIconSvg']" as the xpath, find the element on the page, right click and select inspect. Click on the button element in the html, then right click again, find copy > copy Xpath then drop that in as your xpath.

Thank you for your response! I updated to this but still a bit confused. I don't get an error but the box doesn't close.
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://littlesleepies.com/collections/vip-early-access?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=vip_5_16_2024')
import time
def decline_offer():
decline = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="closeIconContainer"]')))
decline.click()

A minor housekeeping note for newcomers to python: when you can, keep your imports all together at the top. That makes it easier to know what to look for in the driver code.  As suggested by Tony below, things are a little different for button elements with svgs for content. so, try //button[@id='closeIconContainer']/*[name()='svg'][@id='closeIconSvg']

Using Copy XPath is not a good practice because it is a good way to get a very brittle XPath. It's best to write your own. Also, if you're going to find an element by an ID, use By.ID, "closeIconSvg", not XPath.
